# input[type=file] validation

Tags: jquery, validation, file-upload, input

how can I check if the input file is not empty?

I tried:

```
$('#image-file').click(function() {
    if ( ! $('#image-file').val() ) {
    alert('Chose a file!');
    return false;
 }
});
```

but it didn't work.

Answer (score 6):

The `click` event is fired *before* the value is been set. Rather check it during `change` event.

```
$('#image-file').change(function() {
    // ...
});
```

Or, better, during submitting of the form, because the `change` won't be fired when the user selected nothing and the field itself was already empty.

```
$('#form').submit(function() {
    // ...
});
```